# SIMPLE JS Twitter Code for Community College Class

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid, onkeyup

I need help solving this problem for my Intro to JavaScript Course. The problem we need to solve includes changing the `span` id (`numleft`) to report the amount of characters that were entered from the `textarea` id (`comments`) and show how many characters the user has remaining (`255 - comments.length`).

I am stuck after setting the `document.getElementById` and making them equal to each other. Our professor commented hints for us (see below). I am looking for simple code, nothing advanced. But any input will be helpful! I have just been looking at this too long. Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function showComment(){
   
document.getElementById('numleft').innerHTML= document.getElementById('comments').value;

    //find the characters left by subtracting 255 - length
  //condition if we go over 255
  //disable the field or just make the value equal to the first 255 characters.
}    

    
</script>    
    
    
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname"  placeholder="fullname"><span class="err"></span><br>
<div id ="showcomment" >You have <span id="numleft"></span> characters of your 255 left!</div>        
<textarea id="comments" onKeyUp="showComment();"  maxlength="255"></textarea>   
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"> 
    </form>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: "value" is not what you want to set to innerHTML, that returns the text typed in where you want a number. .length should help with this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a twitter widget that you could insert in where you can add a post or what ever
also with the spam, (if you are using it for css) just do
`#numleft { left:1px; top:25%; color:black; }`

> ect.

Comment: hope this helps... at least a little